# Autodeploy DLLs for remote debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, remote-debugging

Suppose I need to debug an .NET desktop application on remote computer (msvsmon.exe). How do I need to deploy the changed binaries in true way?

I started to write a post build MSBuild task that does copy of files to remote share, everything works fine, but I have a feeling that I'm doing something wrong and complex.

Is there an out-of-the box approach for binary file remote server deployments in Visual Studio?

Comment: Do you need to deploy debug dlls or just make the symbols available? I would look at setting up a symbols server on a fileshare and cut out the need to do and additional desktop deployment

Comment: @StephenConnolly, I need to debug DLLs, i.e. I need to do fixes, deploy it on clean machine and debug it on remote dev environment with Visual Studio.

Comment: There are options using msdeploy.exe which should allow you to copy to a specific folder without needing to set up shares on teh target device. e,g, msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:contentPath=C:\TemplateApp1,includeAcls=true -dest:contentPath=C:\contosoApp,computerName=Server1,username=admin,password=pass. Details at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569034(v=ws.10).aspx